# Unknown black area on my homepage

Tags: html, css

There is an horizontal scroll bar on my homepage only (http://balloonup.com) and a black border appears on the right?
How is it possible? Thank you for you help

Comment: in what browser do you see the horizontal scrollbar and where is the black border?

Comment: Maybe [some](http://getfirebug.com/) [of](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#testrender) [these](http://webkit.org/blog/41/introducing-the-web-inspector/) [links](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) will help you..

Comment: Nice site! What exactly are you talking about, it seems ok in IE 8.

Comment: I look at the web inspector but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: I use Chrome on my Mac and I have a black border on the right. Don't you see it??

Comment: @romain I just found it using chrome's developer tools.  What browser did you try to find it in?

Comment: I guess this is a float issue, but I could not catch it in Firefox

Comment: @blake305 when I replace the `float:right` with `float:none` in this line `.yui-g .yui-u,.yui-g .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gb,.yui-g .yui-gc,.yui-g .yui-gd,.yui-g .yui-ge,.yui-g .yui-gf,.yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-gd .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-u{float:right;}` it solves the problem but it completely changes the structure of my page.

Comment: looks like its specifically `.yui-g div.first` causing the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in oldcount.css

```
.home_count {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 420px;
}
```

**remove the width**

Comment: That matches my answer, but there is another problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new solution. Add the inline style `float:none` to the highlighted element.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ok, again it solves the unknown black border problem but modify the position of other elements...I'll work harder...

Comment: Dunno but I spotted a spelling mistake on your "Pricing" page, the interact package you put "Illimited" interactions.

Answer (score 1):

The black "border" is actually the background of your page (#28292B, defined in stylehome.css for the HTML tag). Your problem is that the width of the <BODY> only depends on the window size, not on the content of the elements contained within. You can force the  to the minimum width of the page using:

```
body { min-width: 930px; }
```

Alternatively, if you want IE6 / Opera 6 support (they don't support min-width) you need to add a dummy <DIV> to force the page width. You can use this as the very first  <DIV> of your document:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:930px; height:1px"></div>
```

However, there is another problem that stretches your content more than needed and this is caused by that questions counter on the right side. You can fix that by removing that "**width**" property from the `.home_count` rule as it's useless.

You may also revise that double `.home_count .comma` rule as this seems like an error to me.

Anyway, by applying those two modifications described above your page looks fine on FF4 whatever window size (except for the "Log in" button covering the phone number, but that's out of the scope of this question).

Answer (score -1):

In reset-fonts-grids.css, find all the instances of `float:right` and replace them with `float:none`.

Comment: when I replace the `float:right` with `float:none` in this line `.yui-g .yui-u,.yui-g .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gb,.yui-g .yui-gc,.yui-g .yui-gd,.yui-g .yui-ge,.yui-g .yui-gf,.yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-gd .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-u{float:right;}` it solves the problem but it completely changes the structure of my page.

Comment: @romain I see the problem but it turns out it is with a specific element that doesn't have an id.  Do you know how to edit the page and find a specific element?

Comment: I don't know which element it is...Should I test with every one of them? :(

Comment: @romain No I found the element that has the problem.  Do you want me to take a screenshot of the inspector to show you witch one it is?

Comment: That would be great! Thank's a lot

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
body{
margin-right:-50px;
}
```